# Deploying .NET Microservice API as Serverless in AWS with API Gateway, Code Commit, and Code Pipeline

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, microservices, serverless

I am trying to deploy a .NET microservice API as a serverless application in AWS, utilizing API Gateway, Code Commit, and Code Pipeline. However, I am restricted from using Fargate, Lambda, and Beanstalk for this deployment.
I am seeking guidance on how to set up a serverless deployment for a .NET microservice API using API Gateway, Code Commit, and Code Pipeline without relying on Lambda, Fargate, or Beanstalk. Any insights, best practices, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

I have explored various documentation and tutorials, but most examples focus on serverless deployment using Lambda or Fargate. Unfortunately, due to constraints, these options are not available to me.

Comment: Most Serverless can be implemented using API Gateway -> Lambda -> AWS Services. What is this not available in your case. I cannot see a way using API Gateway without using a Lambda function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've explored a similar approach, following the steps outlined in this tutorial [link](https://dev.to/kayesislam/serverless-microservices-in-asp-net-with-aws-api-gateway-106h). However, my specific constraints prevent me from utilizing Lambda, Fargate, or Beanstalk for the deployment. I'm specifically looking for insights on how to achieve a serverless deployment using API Gateway, Code Commit, and Code Pipeline without relying on those options. If you have any suggestions or alternatives, I would greatly appreciate your input!

Comment: LIke I mentioned - when using API Gateway - it needs to be configured to an endpoint. Many times- its set to invoke an AWS Lambda function. I am not sure how to you use API Gateway so your apps can send a request without API Gateway invoking a Lamba function.